# Вывод статей из БД

Tags: php, html

Пытаюсь вывести все статьи из базы.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в том, что выводится так, как предполагается только первая запись из БД, остальные зачем-то летят в h2>script, откуда ничего не отображается. Как с этим воевать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Экранировать `<>` надо. Вы же понимаете что `<script>` это html тег. И пока он не закроется - не начнется новых тегов.

Comment: Превентивно закрыл </script>в конце тела цикла и всё вывелось, как нужно. Спасибо)

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.strip-tags.php strip_tags можно использовать для удаления всех тегов кроме разрешенных

Comment: Ухх, только сейчас понял проблему целиком. У меня же в самой БД в title статьи стоит <script>.....